# Ember-cli build issue: only able to navigate to index and other routes not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

once building the ember app using ember build -prod, and viewing the app, I only get the index and whenever I try to access another route for example /about I get a 404, same with all of the other routes. All routes work when you serve with the cli.

Below is the current source
https://gitlab.com/remon/ember/tree/master

Comment: is the problem happening locally or in server ?

Comment: @Bek happening locally and when serving on my server. tried creating a new app with a simple about route and has the same issue when building

Comment: I think you need to change the title of question, `Ember-cli build issue: only able to navigate to index and other routes not working` or something like that because route is not site

Comment: how are you serving dist folder after build locally ?

Comment: statically with my go server. tried with a simple node server aswell

Comment: if you type your route with hash` #about` does it work ?

Comment: I think you are having problem with your server, because when you make request e.g `localhost/about` this route does not exist in your server, it should to redirect to serve index.html http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-serve-all-routes-on-a-production-server-exactly/6372/6